# Display a league table on a webpage?

Tags: html, excel, html-table, spreadsheet

Me and a few of my mates are doing a FIFA league between us. I have a server I could upload the league table to. At the minute I'm using a spreadsheet with formulas to work out the points, and the goal difference. Very simple stuff, but saves me having to change everything and I instead just change the wins, draws, losses and goals scored, conceded. The problem is, a lot of the guys use their phones to participate in our chat online, and can't view the spreadsheet on the phone.

So what I'm looking help with is, I know I can create a html table, but is there anyway I can include formulas in it?

Comment: Twitter Bootstrap and javascript

Comment: A much lazier thing to do might just be use an existing service, such as google docs

Comment: Google Docs of course, can't believe I forgot about that. Thanks.

Comment: i'm building an app that will do this very thing :-) will keep you in the loop @apache

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For something this simple, I would recommend [Google Docs](http://docs.google.com).  You can just upload your spreadsheet  It's very easy to use, you can share your spreadsheet with others and it can be viewed in any web browser, or via the Google Docs app available on android and ios.

Otherwise, you can learn Javascript to do the calculations for you in your html table.  Which is also very easy to do, but if you've never used Javascript, it can be a little overwhelming at first.  If you need help with some Javascript, let me know and I can walk you through it (if you decide to choose this route)

Comment: I appreciate your offer on the Javascript, might take you up on it sometime. But I'm learning C++ at the minute, so don't want to be confusing myself. I decided to use Google Docs, had forgot about them. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, any time.  C++ is a great way to start, and it makes it easier to learn js if you already understand a C-based language.